# Android - Threads not executing

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So yeah, my thread isn't executing, or doing the code within it. I just wanted to run a shell script from my sdcard, and show a "loading" circles or "progress" circle or whatever you want to call it. When I click the button to run the thread, I get the progress/loading bar/circle, but it just sits there and does nothing. I've looked at some examples but still cannot figure out what I did wrong. Here's my code:

```
package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.stericson.RootTools.*;
import com.stericson.RootTools.exceptions.RootDeniedException;
import com.stericson.RootTools.execution.CommandCapture;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Install extends Activity{

private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.install);
    Button bInstall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bInstallTheme);
    bInstall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showDialog();
        }
    });
}


public void showDialog(){
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Install.this, "", "Installing Theme", true);
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    thread.start();
}

public void run(){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "su", "sh /sdcard/plasma/scripts/install.sh");
        try {
            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RootDeniedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

private static Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};

}
```

So, am I doing something wrong? Why won't it run my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread doesn't know what to run.  Change

```
public class Install extends Activity{
```

to

```
public class Install extends Activity implements Runnable {
```

and change

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
```

to

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
```